# Writing text after inserting an image in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write a description below an image on a html page, but the text is automatically aligned to right side of the image.
I am a beginne, please help!
Thamks in advance!

```css
.images {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

#my_freaking_id {
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Pictures</h1>
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?random">
  <p>Image 1</p>
</div>
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?random">
  <p>Image 2</p>
</div>

<div id="my_freaking_id">
  It has been a long day, without you my friend and I will tell you all about it when I see you again!<br>I hope our friendship lasts forever!
</div>
```

Comment: I've made your code executable and I can't see the text aligned to the right.

Comment: In the snippet it seems fine Maybe you can update your question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add to css?

```
.images img, .images p {
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Yes but the `<p>` tag (which I hope is meant by description) is already by default `display: block`. So I can't see the issue .. ^^

Comment: I don't see either :/